# Describe the open and closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^1$ in the Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> **Question:** Describe the open and closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^1$ in the Zariski topology.

**My attempt:** By the definition of Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^1$, a closed set is a finite set in $\mathbb{A}^1$. Let $C$ be a closed subset in $\mathbb{A}^1$, so $C = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ - the finite set of points in $\mathbb{A}^1$. Is there any other closed subset in $\mathbb{A}^1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closed sets are the zero sets of polynomials in one variable. The zero sets are precisely the nonempty finite subsets, the empty set (nonzero constants), and the whole space (the zero polynomial). Thus the topology is the finite complement topology.